# How System.out.println(s1==s3.intern()); //return true?

Tags: java, string

I tried doing all manipulation with String.Then I got this Output

```
public class Stringtest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1="abc";
        String s2="abc";
        String s3=new String("abc");
        String s4=new String("abc");
        System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));
        System.out.println(s1==s2);
        System.out.println(s1==s3.intern());
        System.out.println(s3.equals(s4));
    } 
}
```

For:

```
System.out.println(s1==s3.intern()); //return true
```

Why does the result return `true`?

Comment: Chinmoy, try reading the documentation of String (read the top and the docs from `intern()`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interning is making identical immutable objects hold the same reference to save memory. When `s3` is interned, it is set to point to `s1` from the inter pool(as it is a literal it is added there readily).

Since they have the same reference, `==` returns true.